# Umbraco 7 when to use @Umbraco vs @CurrentPage vs @Model in Razor views?

Tags: umbraco

As the title says, when should I use `@Umbraco`, `@CurrentPage` or `@Model` in Razor views to get properties from a node.

`@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue()` returns a strongly typed object, whereas `@CurrentPage` returns a dynamic object. However, with `@Umbraco` I can get a dynamic (`@Umbraco.Content()`) or a strongly typed object (`@Umbraco.TypedContent()`).

Can `@Umbraco` helper do everything that `@CurrentPage` and `@Model` can do? When should I be using which, and why?

Answer (score 16):

You answered most of your question yourself.  `@Model` and `@CurrentPage` are the same except `@CurrentPage` is dynamic.  Both return the current page. That means that, if you interit your views from `UmbracoViewPage`, you can not use `@CurrentPage` because this is only available on the `UmbracoViewTemplate`.  Personally I like `@Model` more than `@CurrentPage`, but it's a personal choice

`@Umbraco` is a completely different beast.  It does not return the current page, but it has a bunch of methods to get other content, media and members in different ways (e.g. xpath).  But also templating and misc methods like:

- Umbraco.If(condition, trueValue [, falseValue])
- Umbraco.Trunctate  // limit text size
- Umbraco.StripHtml // remove html tags
- Umbraco.Search      // full text search

To know more about the @Umbraco, visit the [Umbraco helper documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/)

E.g. If you got an image ID from the current node using

```
var imgId =  @Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("img")
```

then you could use `@Umbraco.TypedMedia(imgId)` to get the image IPublishedContent object.

**Update:**
Next to @Umbraco.Field("propertyAlias") which is one of the template helpers, you can also use @Umbraco.Field( x, "propertyAlias") where x is an IPublishedContent.  This will always return an IHtmlString which makes it impractical for other programming efforts, but makes the Umbraco.Field() a very nice helper method to return properties.

**Update 2:**
Starting from version 7.4, There is a modelBuilder which allows you to define  `UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.HomePage>` and use `@Model.Content.BodyText` later on.  Starting from Umbraco v8 ([on the roadmap](https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/roadmap)), support for dynamics (`CurrentPage` on `UmbracoTemplatePage`) is said to be dropped.  So prepare by using `ModelsBuilder` and `UmbracoViewPage<MyModel>`.

**Update 3:**
Starting from version 8, there will be only an `UmbracoViewPage`.  That means that `CurrentPage` will not be available anymore. Try to use the "models builder" approach to be future proof or [read the first v8 documentation about this topic](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Getting-Started/Design/Rendering-Content/index-v8).